# Regex is not working properly in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

The below regex condition is matching the below website Regex pattern

> Input[\s?[ABCD]+\s?(,\s?[-*][0-9]+%)?](?=\s)

Website link: http://regexr.com/

[image: Screenshot]

But in my WPF application the same Regex is not working.

Code snippet

```
if( Regex.Match(this.textBox.Text, "Input\\[\\s?[ABCD] +\\s ? (,\\s?[-*][0 - 9] +%)?\\](?=\\s)|[?=\\t] |[?=\\s]").Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Regex matched");
}
```

Can anyone please suggest, How can we proceed on this?

Answer (score 3):

> But in my WPF application the same Regex is not working.

No. It's not the same regex, there's an additional `\` after `Input` in your C# app.
This is the same:

```
if( Regex.Match(this.textBox.Text, @"Input\[\s?[ABCD]+\s?(,\s?[-*][0-9]+%)?\](?=\s)").Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Regex matched");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. I got the below exception  parsing "Input\[(\s?[ABCD]+\s?(,\s?[-*][0-9]+%)?\](?=\s)" - Not enough )'s. How can we proceed on this?

Comment: Because the expression you posted now in the comments is different. There's an additional `(` after the first `[`.